# SQL Server diagram filters look up tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, lookup, diagram

When I am adding tables to Database Diagram in SQL Server 2012 it doesn't let me to add look up tables. It just filters them out from the tables list. Is that standard behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By lookup tables, do you mean the related tables? If yes, then you are correct, it filters them out from the Tables list initially when you are adding tables to the diagram.

The way to add the related tables is as follows.

- Add the table with relationships to a database diagram.
- Right-click the table and from the shortcut menu and click **Add Related Tables**.

Source: **Technet**: [How to: Add Related Tables to Diagrams (Visual Database Tools)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190462%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)